# Sheva Brachos at a Bris

Tags: halacha, marriage, brit-milah, sheva-brachos

If a Chosson & Kallah during the first week they got married attended a Bris, should the assembled recite Sheva Brachos after Bentching?

Comment: Is this not a case of *en m'arvin*?

Comment: @DanF  en m'arvin may only apply in certain instances.

Answer (score 3):

This case comes up in the Rishonim, and the answer is simply no, the Seudah must be made Lichvod Chattan veKallah to be considered Simchat and Beit Chattanim. Birkat Hashem (vol. 4 page 345), Shalmei Simcha page 347, Shevet HaLevi (vol. 10 Siman 247:3)

Answer (score 3):

This is a Machlokes haposkim. This happened at the bris of my youngest son 31 years ago. The Kvaters were a couple during sheva brachos and my Dvar Torah was about this subject in which I proved we do say sheva brachos. However, Rav Moshe Heinemann was present (he was Sandak) and I deferred to him. He paskened we should say "shehasimcha bimono," but not sheva brachos. I asked Rav Moshe Bunim Perutinsky the Halacha and he said I was correct, we do say sheva brachos in that case and he wrote this in Sefer Habris, second edition (I only had the first edition and didn't find it there).

Comment: Why would you use a newlywedded couple as kvatrin?? They'd surely be niddah and unable to pass the baby

Comment: Are you discussing a case where nothing was added to the meal for the newlyweds? If something was added then it's not much of a question that the meal is, in part, in their honor and the blessing[s] would be recited

Comment: Some hold the exact  oppisite. If a suedah was intended  as a joint sheva brachos  & Bris you do say Sheva Brochas but not "shehasimcha bimono," You don't say "shehasimcha bimono," by a bris because of the pain caused to the baby. That prevents it from being said even if a sheva brachos is being held at the same time

Comment: Niddah is not a problem, the woman puts the baby down. Nothing has to be added to the meal because the meal does not have to be specifically for the choson and kallah, this shita holds their presence at a seuda that has a minyan creates the chiyuv of sheva brachos. It is explicit in poskim as Rav Heinemann paskened, the simcha bmono is not said for the baby only for the couple.

Answer (score 2):

[Young Israel of North Belmore's Practices and Procedures for Sheva Bruchos](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:8uCumqpEFFoJ%3awww.yinb.org/Sheva%2520Brachos.pdf+sheva+brachot+at+a+bris&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjIQ3taUPJgZTmZOorH2Kx8izMKqNO5xGLndmZP_CEvpTF7vUSs7TnAqHEwLhQAfknMHPSg-fPNcI4PIK58bfak3BMtTkNB3zl44RHQf2q5sCVTRJVqHfLHoVTc1xM9Ed5SziRx&sig=AHIEtbSP3cjDvDS77dN9ao84cF33lsV-nw) says the meal should be prepared specifically for the bride-groom, and as such would not be recited at a Brit.

no sources in the doc though.

Answer (score 0):

[EretzChemda.Org](https://eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=he&pageid=4&cat=7&newsletter=898&article=3437) quoting B'mareh Habezek 7 says a Sheva Brachos and Bris may be combined. In the notes he mentions Yechave Da'as 1:90 and B'Tzeil Hachochmo 1:68.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. If they show up at a bris, does that count?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a rabbi...

My assumption is that the sheva brachot (well, six) should not be recited, because the s'udat mitzvah is not in honor of the chatan and kallah; rather, it is for the mitzvah of milah.

A more interesting question, IMHO, would be, if the parents of the baby boy finally got married after he was born, should they say sheva brachot at the brit.  *Not* a very common occurrence.

Comment: Re "not in honor of": I seem to recall (no source now) that as long as something was added to the meal for the new couple, the _b'rachos_ are said.

Comment: Only if they get married that day, as they would only have one day of Beracha at most.